# Stuck in addview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams labellayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textlayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    for(int i=0 ;i < 2;i++){
        TextView label = new TextView(this);
        EditText text = new EditText(this);

        labellayoutParams.setMargins(40, 30, 30 , 0);
        textlayoutParams.setMargins(60, 30, 30 , 0);
        text.setHint("Type Here");
        label.setText("some text");

        ll.addView(label);
        ll.addView(text);
    }
    this.setContentView(ll);
```

Above code will display output as

Note: Let us assume sometext as textview and ***_*__*_*** as edittext

```
some text ____________ some text _____________
```

but i want a output like this

```
some text ____________

some text ____________
```

i tried setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL) but it gives likes this

```
some text 

_____________

some text

_____________
```

Answer (score 1):

your LinearLayout named ll should have it's property "android:orientation" set to "vertical"

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set linearlayout orientation  [ll.setorientation(VERTICAL)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setOrientation%28int%29) to get the textviews arranged vertically

Comment: i tried that too but it order all in vertically like this 
some text 

_______________

some text

__________________

Answer (score 0):

If u adjust the orientation of your layout vertical, it will work fine....

Answer (score 0):

Try using different layout... I think it cannot be added in a single layout horizontally and vertically(In LinearLayout). You r trying to do it here..